# What does ragtag plugin do

Tags: vim

I am reading the doc still not sure what the plugin does.

https://github.com/tpope/vim-ragtag/raw/master/doc/ragtag.txt

Any further clarification will help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The ragtag plugin only works with certain filetypes, which can cause some confusion, especially when editing an unsaved document.

`*html*,wml,jsp,php,asp*,cf,mason,eruby,liquid,xml,xslt,xsd,docbk`

Answer (score 0):

It adds tags based on shortcuts. Its actually really useful for certain things.

For instance, in rails, you write the word foo (as in all the examples), press `<C-X>+` and you get (^ is where your cursor ends):

```
<%= foo^ %>
```